# How to display output with tinymce (not editing mode)

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have implemented tinymce editor successfully and saved the content into database. After saving I can edit the content in the same editor. But I want to display only the output (not editing mode, without scrollbar). I searched in google but didn't any proper answer. does anybody no how to do this? I have used the following code for editing mode :

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      height: 500,
      theme: 'modern',
      plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
        'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc'
      ],
      toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
      toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample',
      image_advtab: true,
      templates: [
        { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
        { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
      ],
      content_css: [
        '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
        '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
      ]
     });
```

Comment: you  want to show saved data inside tinymce for edit ?

Comment: I only want to show formated data(for view page), not editing mode

Answer (score 1):

I use TinyMCE with Java spring MVC too.
In my Java class:

```
String anyText = "<strong>abc</strong>";

model.addAttribute("anyText","myText");
```

In JSP:

```
<span>${anyText}</span>
```

it shows

> **abc**

if you do like this, it will not show in HTML with bold text.

```
<span><c:out value="${anyText}"/></span>
```